# Rails 5, Mongoid, MongoDB app not running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, mongoid, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Symptoms:
When navigating to the EB URL, page never loads.

I can provide parts of my project config if needed. Here is a portion of the log from my AWS EB instance:

`2018/02/18 09:35:22 [warn] 3060#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2018/02/18 09:46:48 [error] 3064#0: *167 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.4.6, server: _, request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/users", host: "idea-jotter-api-env.ukn765e3m3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2018/02/18 09:46:49 [error] 3064#0: *167 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.4.6, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "idea-jotter-api-env.ukn765e3m3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://idea-jotter-api-env.ukn765e3m3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/users"
2018/02/19 13:11:50 [error] 3064#0: *24659 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.31.179, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock/", host: "52.221.25.234"`